# Route subfolder to main folder with mod_rewrite?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I have problem routing a URL to my PHP, the case is:

```
www.domain.com/controller/**method**/parameter_1/parameter_2
```

I want the URL to become:

```
www.domain.com/controller/parameter_1/parameter_2
```

I want the method removed from the URL.

- How can I do that with .htaccess file?

Comment: you should do some more reading . this should give you a heads up http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: It's simple. 1) Forget about `.htaccess`. 2) Treat `method` as `parameter_1` and `parameter_1` as `parameter_2`.

Comment: nah..the actual case is www.domain.com/blog/article/article-title.....How can the article title become method?

Comment: The `method` in your first `url` is just a placeholder. You can use its value as you wish (i.e. controller's method, 1st param, 2nd param, or anything else). The world will never know about that, its up to you.